# AppleWorks to FileMaker

Tags: appleworks

I have been using AppleWorks -- and think very highly of it.  However, I also know that I need to move on.  Is FileMaker the most similar piece of software?  Can I transfer files from AppleWorks to FileMaker -- or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: Ha ha ha. That's a while ago! :) On what system are your running AppleWorks? The initial release was in 1985; 29 years ago. OS 8.6 if I remember correctly. Tjeez, I am becoming old...

Comment: I see the latest update was in 2004 and only runs on PowerPC/Rosetta. I have no clue about the export features on AppleWorks, but if there are non, I think you need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Filemaker is only a database app, and a pretty hefty one at that. So it will only take the place of one of AppleWorks' modules.

Do you use the drawing and writing component too? There are a number of apps that will open these files but it will depend on your needs. A search on MacInTouch.com for appleworks should turn up a whole bunch of helpful information on converting your files and replacement programs. It is not strictly a forum like Stack Exchange but you can ask relevant questions, but they are heavily moderated.